# After reinstalling unity (16.04, desktop), file missing?

Tags: unity, 16.04, launcher

After reinstalling unity, should there (or should there not) be the following file present:
/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/com.canonical.Unity.Launcher.gschema.xml

Answer (score 0):

## Not necessarily.

I don't think so.  I have a full install of Ubuntu on several machines, and the file is not present.  Furthermore, a Google search turns up no results whatsoever for that file.

Comment: Where else should one 'locate' the famous com.canonical.Unity.Launcher that should (and did until a few days ago on this platform) get invoked near the beginning of each user session ?

Comment: I don't no why, but my Google-search turned up a few results and normally the file should be in the mentioned location.
Maybe look in `/usr/local/share/glib-2.0/schemas/` ? Otherwise carry out a file-search...

Comment: Hmm, interesting it turned something up.  Mine didn't find anything before, and now it finds three; one of which is the AU post, and the two others which are direct citations.  Could you share any others you have found?